# Android ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 how to test multiplie activites

Tags: java, android, testing, testcase

im trying to understand how to work with tests. Not good but for one activity with simple controls i create test , and it's going very well.

Than i start to try with 2 or more activities and i stuck here . 
From one activity after some controls click i going to other activity (it's how in app ) but how to do it in tests i can find . 
For getting controls from first activity i write

```
MyFirstTestActivity mftActivity;
....
super(MyFirstTestActivity.class);
mftActivity = getActivity();
```

and i can easy work with controls from first activity, but how to get other activities ?
After click on last button in first activity, i make delay and other activity showed for me , but i cant test there anything. Please help someone if any one know, documentation not tell me nothing about it , and i googlin full day and not find anything